# Добавление сортировки в аргументы цикла через функцию

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть функция, которая добавляет способ сортировки в аргументы цикла wp_query.

```
function wpestate_my_order($orderby) { 
    global $wpdb; 
    global $table_prefix;
    $orderby = $table_prefix.'postmeta.meta_value DESC, '.$table_prefix.'posts.ID DESC';
    return $orderby;
}
```

Не могу понять, по какому, собственно, полю происходит сортировка, из того, что я вижу и могу понять - по какому-то мета полю, без уточнения по какому именно. Как так?

И второй момент, правильно ли понимаю, чтобы изменить на сортировку по дате обновления, надо `postmeta.meta_value` заменить на `posts.post_modified` ?

Comment: да, все верно
http://help.wpresidence.net/article/order-by-edit-date/

Comment: @madfan41k, так, а все таки, как работает их основное правило: сортировка по мета значению, но без указания по какому

Answer (score 0):

Запрос к базе данных WordPress проходит через несколько фильтров. Вы привели только один - фильтр инструкции `ORDERBY`.

Для других инструкций есть другие фильтры, например `get_meta_sql`. Полностью запрос можно фильтровать в `pre_get_posts`.

Фильтров довольно много, их надо искать по документации. Можно начать отсюда: https://wp-kama.ru/hooks